# Calculating the percent left in a month using UIDatePicker in iOS8

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

Hoping someone can help me. I am trying to do a simple dashboard (new to coding here. Learning Swift 1.0 just to get used to the language first) and I want one of the items in the dashboard to show the percent of the month that has been completed.

After a lot of toying I thought I wrote something that would work. When I run the application I get no errors however when I press the button that this code is written into nothing happens for this segment of the dashboard.

```
@IBAction func enterButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {

    let stringFromSalesField = salesTextField.text
    let doubleFromSalesField = (stringFromSalesField as NSString).doubleValue
    let intFromSalesField = doubleFromSalesField

    monthlySales.hidden = false
    monthlySales.text = "$" + "\(intFromSalesField)"

    let stringFromGoalField = enterGoalTextField.text
    let doubleFromGoalField = (stringFromGoalField as NSString).doubleValue
    let intFromGoalField = doubleFromGoalField

    moneyTillGoal.hidden = false
    moneyTillGoal.text = "$" + "\(intFromGoalField - intFromSalesField)"

    percentComplete.hidden = false
    percentComplete.text = "\((intFromSalesField / intFromGoalField) * 100)" + "%"

    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd"
    let strDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(datePicker.date)
    todaysDate.text = strDate
    todaysDate.hidden = false


    let dateComponents = NSDateComponents()
    let day = dateComponents.day
    let month = dateComponents.month



    if  dateComponents.month == 01 {
        percentThruMonth.text =  "\((day / 31) * 100)" + "%"
    }
    else if  dateComponents.month == 03 {
        percentThruMonth.text =  "\((day / 31) * 100)" + "%"
    }
    else if dateComponents.month == 05 {
        percentThruMonth.text =  "\((day / 31) * 100)" + "%"}
    else if dateComponents.month == 07 {
        percentThruMonth.text =  "\((day / 31) * 100)" + "%"}
    else if dateComponents.month == 08 {
        percentThruMonth.text =  "\((day / 31) * 100)" + "%"}
    else if dateComponents.month == 10 {
        percentThruMonth.text = "\((day / 31) * 100)" + "%"}
    else if dateComponents.month == 12 {
        percentThruMonth.text =  "\((day / 31) * 100)" + "%"}
    else if dateComponents.month == 06 {
        percentThruMonth.text =  "\((day / 30) * 100)" + "%"}
    else if dateComponents.month == 09 {
        percentThruMonth.text =  "\((day / 30) * 100)" + "%"}
    else if dateComponents.month == 11 {
        percentThruMonth.text =  "\((day / 30) * 100)" + "%"}
    else if dateComponents.month == 02 {
        percentThruMonth.text =  "\((day / 28) * 100)" + "%"}



}
```

Thoughts? Is there an easier way to do this that I am missing? I have all the outlets hooked up. I triple checked that.

Comment: "Learning Swift 1.0" I suggest you start with Swift 2.0 or whatever is current. It's a very different language; you'll just find yourself confused when you have to relearn everything.

Comment: Use the debugger! A simple breakpoint will tell you whether your code is even running. It might not be, you know.

Comment: Your code is rather silly. There are classes that know how many days a month has.

Comment: I appreciate constructive information. I am still learning as I said and I am self teaching myself. No need to say the code is silly, rather help to make it less silly would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm being constructive. I'm subtly pointing you to the documentation: e.g. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendricalCalculations.html

Answer (score 0):

You can say something like:

```
let curDate = NSDate()
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let comps: NSDateComponents = calendar.components([NSCalendarUnit.Month,  NSCalendarUnit.Day,  NSCalendarUnit.Year], fromDate: curDate)

comps.day = 1 //first moment of the month

let firstDateMonth = calendar.dateFromComponents(comps)
comps.month = comps.month+1 //first moment of next month
let lastDateMonth = calendar.dateFromComponents(comps)

let totalInterval = lastDateMonth?.timeIntervalSinceDate(firstDateMonth!)

let intervalToEnd = lastDateMonth?.timeIntervalSinceNow

let percentLeft = intervalToEnd!/totalInterval!
print(percentLeft)
```

To do the calculation. You should try setting breakpoints or printing something in your method to see if it's getting called. If it's not getting called you likely haven't setup the action correctly.